# StoreKit 2: Type 'Product' has no member 'request'

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am starting with StoreKit 2. Trying to implement a simple fetch product function, but Xcode doesn't find the **request** function for **Product**

Trying the following code, which I see on Apple's WWDC tutorial, and other tutorials

```
import StoreKit
import SwiftUI

class Store: ObservableObject {
    
     func requestProducts() async {
             do{
                 let storeProducts = try await Product.request (with:["com.v6"])
             }catch {
                 print ("Failed requesting prodcuts \(error)")
             }
    }
}
```

But I get a compiler error: Type 'Product' has no member 'request'

[image: see also image attached]

Any idea why?

Comment: Because `Product.request` doesn't exist. Here's the documentation that shows what is available on `Product`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product Maybe you're looking for`products(for:)`?

Comment: @jnpdx am looking at the WWDC22 video tutorial: https://youtu.be/E5Vz11NyR2g?t=462  and they clearly use Product.request, same in some other tutorials such as: https://youtu.be/JJG3xI5FmFY?t=443 ...

Comment: Both of those are from 2021, not 2022. Often APIs change between announcement and release. One way or another, you can check the documentation I linked for the current availability of APIs on `Product`

Comment: @jnpdx usualy they are deprecated and then last for a few more versions before completely removed, but I'll find the replacement if any in the docs, thanks.

Comment: Things are only deprecated if they actually make it to the release version. If it was prerelease, they can get changed before actual release date.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api

Answer (score 0):

Use `products(for: )` instead of `request(with: )`.